# Errno 13: Passing Python variables to bash script

Tags: python, bash, variables, scripting, subprocess

Currently I am testing a very simple piece of code. I simply want to write a python script that sets a variable and then pass that variable into a bash script for use.

## Python Script:

```
from subprocess import check_call
a = str(3)
check_call(["/home/desktop/bash2pyTest/test.sh", a], shell=False)
```

## Bash Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This number was sent from the py script: " $1
```

I have read other Q&As that are related to this topic; however, I am not finding a solution that I am conceptually understand; thus, the syntax above might be incorrect. I have tried a few other methods as well; however, I keep receiving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cassandra/desktop/bash2pyTest/callVar.py", line 3, in <module>
    check_call(["/home/cassandra/desktop/bash2pyTest/test.sh", a],    shell=False)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 537, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 524, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
chmod +x /home/desktop/bash2pyTest/test.sh
```

in shell. The file you are trying to execute is not executable.

Or another option in python script:

```
check_call(["sh","/home/desktop/bash2pyTest/test.sh", a], shell=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says that permission is denied. I tested your code, and it works fine on my machine. However, you will need to be sure that the user running the command has sufficient privileges for the `test.sh` script. Most importantly, be sure that `test.sh` has execute permissions set. That's often the most easily missed permission.